# How to check for successful response from API in rails by just using status code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am **consuming an API** using a gem in Ruby on Rails. The gem makes the API call for me and returns the **status code as an integer** (for example 200, 201 e.t.c.) and the **data response** from the API.

```
def get_cars
  status_code, data = MyGem::Cars.get_cars
  if status_code in SUCCESSFUL_RESPONSE_CODES
    # Perform data manipulation
  else
    raise "There was an error processing the request. Status code #{status_code}"
  end
end
```

Now I have manually initialised `SUCCESSFUL_RESPONSE_CODES` as a list containing integers of successful codes I found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

Is this list defined somewhere in Ruby/RoR to avoid manually defining it?

Comment: what code are you using to construct the HTTP request?

Comment: That's all done by the gem internally all I get back is the status code as an integer and data

Comment: can you please tell us which gem?

Comment: @ElChapo checking the HTTP status code seems a bit low level given that the gem should handle the connection details for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. This is a custom gem so I will follow your advice and move the status handling logic to the gem as lacostenycoder suggested in his answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect any widely supported gem to use standard HTTP response codes to determine if the HTTP response was a `success`.  For example:

```
require 'open-uri' # Rails loads this by default.
res = open('http://example.com')
res.status
=> ["200","OK"]
status.include?'OK'
=>true
status.include?'200'
=> true
```

So long as you trust the gem code making your request to handle standard HTTP response codes, you should be ok.  Here's another example using HTTParty gem

```
require 'HTTParty'
res = HTTParty.get('https://example.com')
res.success?
=> true
```